# Jackson JSON XML simplify with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, mule, esb

I have an XML document generated with Jackson JSON processor in Mule ESB. After converting JSON to XML I have this document:

```
<org.mule.module.json.JsonData>
  <node class="org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode">
    <__nodeFactory/>
    <__children>
      <entry>
        <string>author</string>
        <org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode>
          <__nodeFactory reference="../../../../__nodeFactory"/>
          <__children>
            <entry>
              <string>application</string>
              <org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
                <__value>web</__value>
              </org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
            </entry>
            <entry>
              <string>name</string>
              <org.codehaus.jackson.node.ArrayNode>
                <__nodeFactory reference="../../../../../../../../../../__nodeFactory"/>
                <__children>
                <org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode>
                  <__nodeFactory reference="../../../../../../../../../../../../__nodeFactory"/>
                  <__children>
                  <entry>
                    <string>name</string>
                    <org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
                    <__value>Connected</__value>
                    </org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
                  </entry>
                  <entry>
                    <string>checked</string>
                    <org.codehaus.jackson.node.BooleanNode reference="../../../../../../../../../../entry[11]/org.codehaus.jackson.node.ArrayNode/__children/org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode/__children/entry[2]/org.codehaus.jackson.node.BooleanNode"/>
                  </entry>
                  <entry>
                    <string>checked_at</string>
                    <org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
                    <__value>2015-09-10T18:55:58+03:00</__value>
                    </org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
                  </entry>
                  </__children>
                </org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode>
                <org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
                  <__value>Tested</__value>
                </org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
                <org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
                  <__value>Tested</__value>
                </org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
                </__children>
              </org.codehaus.jackson.node.ArrayNode>
            </entry>
          </__children>
        </org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode>
      </entry>
    </__children>
  </node class="org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode">
</org.mule.module.json.JsonData>
```

This XML is too complicated to work with XPath and I want to simplify them with simple XSLT to get something like this:

```
<object>
  <entry>
    <key>author</key>
    <value>
      <object>
        <entry>
          <key>application</key>
          <value>web</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <key>name</key>
          <value>
            <array>
              <item>
                <object>
                  <entry>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <value>Connected</value>
                  </entry>
                  <entry>
                    <key>checked</key>
                    <value/>
                  </entry>
                  <entry>
                    <key>checked_at</key>
                    <value>2015-09-10T18:55:58+03:00</value>
                  </entry>
                </object>
              </item>
              <item>Tested</item>
              <item>Tested</item>
            </array>
          </value>
        </entry>
      </object>
    </value>
  </entry>
</object>
```

The rules are next:

1. node `org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode` and `node[@class='org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode']` should be transformed to node `object` with child nodes `entry`.
2. node `entry` for `object` should be transformed to node `entry` with child nodes `key` and `value`.
3. node `org.codehaus.jackson.node.ArrayNode` and `node[@class='org.codehaus.jackson.node.ArrayNode']` should be transformed to node `array` with child nodes `item`.
4. all child nodes of `__children` node for `array` should be transformed to `item` with value.
5. another value types should be transformed as is.

I tried to do this logic with XSLT but don't know how to do it well with nested objects and arrays (at all):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode | node[@class='org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode']">
    <object select="__children"><xsl:apply-templates /></>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <entry><xsl:apply-templates /></entry>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry/*[1]">
    <key><xsl:apply-templates /></key>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry/*[2]">
    <value><xsl:apply-templates /></value>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

May be there is any way to easy simplify JSON XML in Mule more easy.

Comment: Please show what you tried and where you are stuck. We can't just write the whole task for you: [help/on-topic].

Comment: "*This XML is too complicated to work with XPath*"  There is no such thing: by definition, XPath can handle *any* XML document. And XSLT depends on XPath to select nodes in the input document - so if Xpath cannot handle it, neither can XSLT. -- However, it is true that the document you show us cannot be processed at all, because it has an attribute on a closing tag: `</node class="org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode">`.

Comment: I added XSLT that I tried but it has problems with nested objects (no `object` tag included) and I don't know how to do it properly with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the version 3.7. Dataweave is your answer:

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/dataweave#_json_to_xml